# Increase of Virtual Memory after update of CentOS7

Tags: centos, memory, virtual-memory

I have made system updates on CentOS7 and now my Virtual Memory is full used. Before the updates the virtual memory was completely empty/swap

Why? Is it a problem? How can I decrease the virtual memory uded? Maybe restarting the system?

Comment: please provide more clear information, virtual memory doesn't need be increase in linux, maybe you mean before the upgrade your swap space was not used?

Comment: yes sorry...
before the swap space was not used... now is full used

Answer (score 0):

This command will show memory usage sorted by virtual memory size:

```
ps auwx --sort -vsz
```

This will show memory usage sorted by real size:

```
ps auwx --sort -rss
```

That should lead you in the direction of seeing what's taking up memory.